# Google+ API button with oAuth

Tags: php, google-api, google-plus

I am making PHP application that will load posts of specific friend and then add ability to plus his post, similar to Google+ button available on site...

I found Google+ button posting link with JSON:

`"method":"pos.plusones.insert", "id":"post_id"`

but I can't authorize with PHP oAuth on this...
I tried **access_token** and **id_token** in

`Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=token`

but both are returning error wrong Auth token...

Is there a way to authorize or add this plus to post with oAuth token?

I know Google have new API, but is there any way to make this request?

Thanks!

**Update**

Code:

```
$like = 'POST ID';
$key = json_decode($_SESSION['access_token'], true);

$headers = array('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8', 'Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=' .$key['access_token']. '');
$url = 'https://clients6.google.com/rpc?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$post_data = '[{"method":"pos.plusones.insert","id":"' .$like. '",
                "params":{"cdx":"4f79f","id":"https://www.google.com/","source":"widget","track":"[[[null,[1,1618239,[],1,90]],[[null,null,[]]]]]","container":"","abtk":"","userId":"@viewer","groupId":"@self"},
                "jsonrpc":"2.0",
                "key":"pos.plusones.insert",
                "apiVersion":"v1"}]';

$fr = curlData($url, $headers, $post_data); //function to send CURL Post request
echo $fr;
```

And it returns:

```
[
 {
  "error": {
   "code": 401,
   "message": "Token invalid - Invalid AuthSub token.",
   "data": [
    {
     "domain": "global",
     "reason": "authError",
     "message": "Token invalid - Invalid AuthSub token.",
     "locationType": "header",
     "location": "Authorization"
    }
   ]
  },
  "id": "POST ID"
 }
]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you show us what the exact error is? Also, if you could give us some code, what you think it should do, and what it is doing, that would help us help you figure it out.

Comment: I am not new here, it looks like Stack Overflow deleted my previous activities... But thanks! :) I updated post with code...

Answer (score 1):

This isn't going to work.

The API used by the +1 button is not a publicly accessible API. Since it's not public, you cannot acquire an access token that allows your code to insert +1's on behalf of a user. The only way to insert +1's is to use the [+1 button](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/).

The Google+ API toggle on the Google API Console actually refers to the [public data APIs](https://developers.google.com/+/api/).